# the color of turnips

Tags: word-meaning

> Maggie had come from Tennessee. Her hair was **the color of turnips** and
>   she laughed.

This is from a novel "Sarah, Plain and Tall". Does it mean "Her hair was white hair because of her age"?

Comment: turnips aren't really white, they're a bit yellowish... Let's call it a 'countryside' reference in which the author avoided the clichéd 'golden corn'  ..

Comment: I've never seen anyone with [turnip-colored hair](https://opimedia.azureedge.net/-/media/images/men/editorial/articles/magazine-articles/1983/07-01/how-to-make-turnip-kraut/turnip.jpeg). If her hair was white, there is no indication that was necessarily because of age. I've known young people with near-white hair.

Comment: @Tetsujin Does this "turnips" mean flowers of turnips? I thought it means the part we eat.

Comment: @J.R.: *On average*, non-native Anglophones are probably less familiar with younger people being fair/flaxen-haired (such people being highly unusual in African or Asian "races"). But there is a tendency to assume ***a white-haired lady*** has become so through age, even among native Anglophones. So it's at least *possible* the writer specifically wanted to avoid getting too close to that implication if Maggie is in fact quite young. Or maybe she just wanted to show off her literary / poetic skills with a slightly unusual / unexpected metaphoric reference.

Comment: @Fumble - I think it's meant to cryptic. Here's a fuller excerpt: _Papa leaned back in the chair. "I've placed an advertisement in the newspapers. For help." / "You mean a housekeeper?" I asked, surprised. / "No," said Papa slowly. "Not a housekeeper." He paused. "A wife." / Caleb stared at Papa. "A wife? You mean a Mother? " / "That, too," said Papa. "Like Maggie." / Matthew, our neighbor to the south, had written to ask for a wife and mother for his children. And Maggie had come from Tennessee. Her hair was the color of turnips and she laughed._

Comment: Lets hope he was not referring to the reddish-purple colour frequently seen on the outside of turnips.

Comment: I still think we're wrong to think that turnips/corn/flax are *white*. They're not, & in literary terms they always mean "blond[e]"

Comment: @James - they're swedes, not turnips. Swede, a beet, round, purple skin. Turnip, like a very pale carrot.

Comment: If "turnip" means "blond," I like the theory that says we are talking about the [flowers](http://www.bridgenature.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/TurnipFlowers-199A.lr_.jpg), not the [roots](http://demandware.edgesuite.net/sits_pod32/dw/image/v2/BBBW_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-jss-master/default/dwec0dbeac/images/products/farmseed/00233_01_purple_top.jpg).

Comment: ...but how many people would ever know what colour a turnip flower is... only a farmer would *ever* have seen one. & I've just discovered what a turnip looks like. Never seen on in my life before & I'm nearly 60. I was thinking parsnip vs swede, but these things are some kind of 'half way swede' so I'm right out of this discussion ;-) This may be why... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnip_(terminology)

Comment: Hi @Tetsujin  Many years ago, my parents used to grow turnips and swedes on their farm. The part of the turnip that is under the soil is a pale colour, almost white for some varieties. However, for some varieties of turnip, the top of the turnip that protrudes out of the ground takes on the same reddish-purple colour as swedes. Which is not very surprising because swedes were originally developed by crossing a type of turnip with a type of cabbage.

Comment: @James - you may indeed be 100% correct. I'm still reeling from the discovery that a turnip looks like an oversized radish... I've either never seen one, had my eyes shut for however many years, or something. .. I've always considered the round things swedes & the long things turnips [or parsnips, but that might be a UK north/south thing] I do think I've reached the point where the OP's hair colour has gone off-scale... could be *anything* from white, through yellow, to purple... or green... don't forget the leaves...

Comment: The narrator is a child, right?  Could the reference be to the color of turnips after they'd been cooked and served?  In which case certainly light yellow or blonde.

Comment: @J.R.: From [Yet another 25 Scots words that must not die](https://bloodandporridge.co.uk/wp/?p=8673) - *if you call someone a **tumshie-heid**, you’re calling them a ‘**turnip-head**’, i.e. a moron*. That's the first association that comes to mind for me given the cited usage. The second association simply being that invoking imagery based on turnips alludes to "humble rusticity" in terms of character (and perhaps "homeliness" in terms of appearance). But it really is up to the reader what he takes from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ve upvoted this question because it ignited an interesting discussion in the comments among puzzled ELL regulars.

After reading through the comments, I feel pretty safe about saying this much:

- **It’s not a common idiom**. Although I have managed to a few other references to ‘turnip colored hair’, it’s not by any means ubiquitous. It’s not the kind of descriptor a witness would use to describe a suspect, but it kindles the imagination when used in a literary work.
- Turnips can be white, purple, red, green, bright yellow, or pale yellow, depending on whether we are talking about the root, stalk, flower, or the cooked vegetable.
- Because human hair is rarely pink, purple, or green (unless colored), this probably refers to a color somewhere between white and blonde.
- The person being referenced in the story is a "mail-order bride.” From what little I read of the story, I got the impression that she was not all that elderly when the children met her, so I’m inclined to think the expression alludes to a light blonde color of hair, not an elderly gray.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The flesh of a turnip is white or nearly white. In American English, the most common phrase used for a woman whose hair is so blonde (not due to age) that it's nearly white is **platinum blonde**.  However, this phrase often has connotations of either elitism (since hair that is naturally this color is rare and stereotypically desirable) or some degree of tasteless social striving (since you'd need to chemically bleach your hair to an extreme degree to achieve this color artificially).

What I believe the writer is trying to convey is that this Maggie has very blonde hair, nearly white, but either Maggie herself or the person describing her is so far removed from any sort of "high society" that they'd be unfamiliar with the phrase "platinum blonde" or any of the elitism associated with it.  The turnip is a lowly, unglamorous vegetable, and to associate a hair color with such an unglamorous vegetable inverts the high status traditionally accorded to blondes.